# Magento 1.9 Where to get a full list of all magento functions / methods and their explanations

Tags: magento-1.9, documentation

where to find a complete list of all Magento functions and methods and the explanation of them?

Answer (score 0):

Magento Developer Official document:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/

Comment: This link doesn't show a list of functions / methods. we can't really use it as code reference.